# configurar DateTimePicker con intervalos de 15 minutos en los valores

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo colocar intervalos de 15 minutos y en la fecha si estoy en el día miércoles 21 octubre del 2020 y las fechas anteriores no estén habilitadas?.

Comment: Para evitar el cierre de tu pregunta agrega que llevas hecho

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Como esta definido tu control en el html? usas algun tipo de framework de visualizacion?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que buscas el `stepping`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#yourTimePickerElement').datetimepicker({
    stepping: 15
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <input id="yourTimePickerElement" placeholder="yyyy/MM/dd" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Comment: No veo por que deba esperar algun intento de stepping, si esta mostrando que ya tiene el datetimepicker configurado. Seguro desconoce el stepping.

Comment: Si tu no le quieres contestar, esta bien. Si responderle va en contra de las reglas, reportalo. Si el post del OP esta mal formulado, reportalo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso me funciono @Excorpion me funciono, estaba investigando y por este medio fue mi ultima opción,

Comment: BetaM esperaba que tu mostraras algo de investigacion para dar una respuesta parece... pero veo que has usado el datetimepicker a gusto y seguro desconoces el stepping. Trata de siempre buscar la documentacion, y que opciones te entrega. En mi caso asi lo descubri antes, @AndresOrtega

Comment: Agradesco la edicion @RuslanLopez

Comment: Ayúdanos a responder preguntas realizadas en base a [ask], para mantener la calidad de la información en el sitio, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias lo pude solucionar.

Comment: @Andres si la respuesta te sirvió la mejor forma de agradecer es marcando la misma como aceptada